# Images wont load asynchronously to fill UIImageView on swift project

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

I am fairly new at swift development. My first project is almost complete, except that I cannot get images to download asynchronously. When I compile my project, I do not see the `UIImage` placeholder I set in, so I am not entirely sure whats going on. I am sure that my issue is binding. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
// Async Code

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "item" {
        postTitle = String()
        postLink = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "title" {
            postTitle += data
        } else if eName == "link" {
            postLink += data
        }
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        let blogPost: BlogPost = BlogPost()
        blogPost.postTitle = postTitle
        blogPost.postLink = postLink
       //blogPost.postImage = postImage
        blogPosts.append(blogPost)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return blogPosts.count
}

// Image View
func asyncLoadShotImage(imageView : UIImageView) {

    let downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.iShots.processdownload", nil)

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue) {

        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.imageUrl)!)

        var image : UIImage?
        if data != nil {
           self.imageData = data!
            image = UIImage(data: data!)!
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }


}
```

And this is called like so:

```
asyncLoadShotImage(cell.myImageLabel)
```

A cell from my project:

[image: i.imgur.com/9WojOuA.png]

Comment: I assume that all of that `NSXMLParser` code is unrelated to your question at hand? If so, maybe you should remove that. Likewise, `didReceiveMemoryWarning` doesn't seem relevant. What you're not showing us, though, is where you're calling `asyncLoadShotImage` (I assume you're doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

The `asyncLoadShotImage` is loading `NSData` from the contents of `self.imageUrl`. And it later references `self.imageData`. It's worrisome that you have cell image retrieval logic referring to `self` (which I presume is the table view controller). If you had a dozen cells asynchronously retrieving images, so which URL is `imageUrl` then referencing? I'd expect to see the code referencing an array of image URLs, not just one. Which cell is `imageData` for? I'd expect to see a `NSCache` of image data objects, not just a single `NSData`.

If you're not seeing your images be populated, then you should have `asyncLoadShotImage` log the URL it's trying to retrieve the image from and make sure it's OK. Also, I'm inferring from the `imageData` references that you're trying to do some caching of images, but you're not showing us your logic for when this `asyncLoadShotImage` is retrieved, but there could be a bug there, too.

Bottom line, make sure this function is getting called like you think it should, and make sure that the URL it's using looks right. You should probably also log some message if the image retrieval failed, so you know it failed. Ideally, you should use something like `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskForURL(url, completionHandler:...)`, because that provides a `NSError` object you can use for diagnosing problems. Right now you're flying blind.

Finally, you say you can't see your image view. Is it possible that it is there, but rather that there are incorrect constraints that make it impossible to see? I would run the app, hit the pause button:

[image]

And then, at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

When you do that, you'll get a long text description of the views, and check the `frame` for the image views in question.

By the way, you can also confirm where the image views  are by using the view debugger (though it's sometimes hard to identify non-visible, i.e. zero width, views):

[image]

---

That having been said, there are a ton of deeper issues here:

- Cells are reused. So you cannot be confident that by the time the asynchronous image retrieval request, that the `imageView` you reference is still being used for the same row it was when you started the request. (It might be used for a completely different row in the table/collection view by the time the asynchronous method returns.) Rather than passing this routine a `UIImageView` reference, you should instead be passing it the information that it can use to later use to (a) find the appropriate row in the table (in case other rows were inserted/deleted between the time we made the request and when the image was retrieved); and (b) see if the cell for that row is still visible; and (c) only update that image view if we found the appropriate, visible cell.
- You really need this to be a cancelable request. If the user quickly scrolls from the first row to the 100th row in the table, you don't want it to have to retrieve the first 99 images before retrieving the images for the then visible rows. Otherwise, on a slow network connection, it could easily be a minute or so before the image retrieves (and that's an eternity when the user is sitting there, standing at an imageless view).

  Bottom line, if a cell scrolls off screen, you probably want to cancel the old request.
- Your `asyncLoadShotImage` is creating a new queue every time you call it. This means that you're not constraining how many threads the app will create. If this function is going to be called multiple times, you probably want to use a single queue (and I'd be inclined to use an operation queue, one that is concurrent, but constrains the degree of concurrency).
- If you're going to be doing caching of images, you should really have `didReceiveMemoryWarning` empty that cache. If you're going to do caching, you might want to cache both to persistent storage as well as memory, so that if you have to purge memory under memory pressure, you still have a copy in local persistent storage, rather than having to retrieve the image all over.

Bottom line, to do this properly is non-trivial. You might want to consider using one of the `UIImageView` categories out there (such as those included with SDWebImage or AFNetworking). It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I got my issue working with AFNetworking